# Are there any default set of rules for SonarQube other than the default rules from the Sonar Java plugin?

Tags: java, sonarqube

As stated in the title of this post - I am looking for locations or advice how I should construct the rule database for my SonarQube instance. Are there any preset set of rules other than the default Sonar Way (from the Java plugin or the FindBugs plugin) which I can browse and investigate if they fit to my purpose better than the default rules?

My idea is that people may have configured a set of rules for their code base in a certain way which other people may benefit from, using certain aspects of the code base which may be applicable to other code bases as well.

I am running SonarQube v5.4 and my goals of this environment is to analyze the a code base of a bit less than 2 million lines to investigate how this static code analysis tool can be used to improve the structure of the project and increase the number of bugs found.

Comment: To be clear: you're looking not necessarily for new/different rules, but for new groupings of rules?

Comment: Exactly, I am looking for sets of rules which have been adapted to fit a certain type of code base or where a certain number of rules have been added to include some aspects of a code base. I have not found such a location where this type of sets can be found, thus I am asking here to investigate if there are any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As lead maintainer of java plugin : we do not provide any other profile than the sonar way profile today (soon there will be another one with security rules).

And we are not aware of any provider of quality profiles outside of SonarSource.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That was unfortunate, maybe there will be profiles available in the future for SonarQube.